# How can I draw the transition diagram of a Markov chain?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I apologize for my heaviness as  I am a *Mathematica* novice. Is there a kind soul who can tell me how to draw diagrams like those shown on page 158, 160 and 161 of this document.[Chaine de Markov](http://epfl.wikispaces.com/file/view/MDS_MOD7_0607.pdf)

I oversee several plotting examples unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 14):

Here's an answer straight from the documentation for `DiscreteMarkovProcess`

```
Graph[DiscreteMarkovProcess[3, {{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, 
    {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which graphs a fourth order Markov chain with the specified transition matrix and initial state 3. The colors occur because some of the states (1 and 2) are transient and some are absorbing (in this case, state 4). You can customize the appearance of the graph by looking at the help file for `Graph`.

Comment: Please note that this solution is available only starting with version 9.  (Such a graph can be drawn with earlier versions of *Mathematica* but it takes a lot of fiddling.)